# Android get a fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried in a lot of different ways but I didn't find a solution.
How can I retrieve a fragment instance from Activity A in Activity B?
Because I need it for let the fragment reload its content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? why do need the fragment instance? tell me your goal maybe there is a lot easier way

Comment: there are other ways to share data between such views, tell us exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: In case you need such behavior when I would admit that your architecture is incorrect. You should never have an ability to retrieve an instance of the fragment from the activity which doesn't hold it.

Comment: If you want to achieve this quickly, you can add event bus functionality in your codebase and put an event on bus when fragment is needed to update its content. Of course, fragment need to register for bus events. There are many libraries out there

Comment: I tried (In Activity B) for istance: getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById() or activityAinstance.getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById() and in all the attempts I received a NullPointerException. I need the fragment instance to call a method inside the fragment class

Comment: NPE is a correct exception here. While you on ActivityB, existing of the instance of the ActivityA is not guaranteed, so the fragment's instance is not guaranteed also.

Comment: But I start the AcitivityB from ActivityA. So, the ActivityA instance should be guaranteed, right?

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't. What exactly you need to achieve?

Comment: Use EventBus is the correct way